# behaviour of descriptor concept in python (confusing)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, descriptor

I understood python descriptor but I have a little confusion about this..

if you have a class descriptor as follows

```
class Descriptor(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        print 'getting'
        return self.value
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print 'setting'
        self.value = value
    def __delete__(self, instance):
        print 'deleting'
        del self.value
```

and a class whose attributes we want to manage is something like this..

```
class Test(object):
    name = Descriptor()
    def __init__(self, name):
        print 'init test'
        self.name = name
```

when I create object of class Test and do something it gives me answer like this...

```
t = Test('abc')
init test
setting
>>> t.name
getting 
'abc'
>>> del t.name
deleting
>>> t
<__main__.Test object at 0x013FCCD0>
>>> t.name
getting
```

Now I want to have a class Test1 something like this..

```
class Test1(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        print 'init test1'
        self.name = Descriptor()
        self. value = value
```

and if I create object of Test1 and try to access attribute of instance of Test1, I get output something like this..

```
t1 = Test1(12)
t1.name
>>> getting
>>> 12
>>> t1.name = 30
>>> setting
```

Q 1) my question is that is this name attribute declared in init of Test1, is bound to instance of Test1 or not... because when I try to get attribute dictionary of t1, it return empty dict...

```
t1.__dict__
>>> {}
```

same for class Test's instance t

```
 t.__dict__
 >>> {}
```

When I add a new attribute to any of these instances, like this...

```
 t.some = 'some'
 >>> t1.some = 'some'
```

and again if I try to access attribute dictionary it gives me only which I have added just now.. now all instance attribute

```
t.__dict__
>>> {'some': 'some'}
>>> t1.__dict__
>>> {'some': 'some'}
```

Q 2) So what is the difference between instance attributes defined in init (like variable name and value in class Descriptor and Test) and attributes defined after instance creation (like variable t.some).

Q 3) How class Test is different than class Test1.

Comment: I don't have quite the same behaviour here - what I get is the expected behaviour :
>>> from desc import *
>>> t1 = Test1(12)
init test1
>>> t1.name
<desc.Descriptor object at 0x143d450>
>>> t1.__dict__
{'name': <desc.Descriptor object at 0x143d450>, 'value': 12}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Test1` your `Descriptor` isn't really used as a descriptor, it's just a normal attribute called `name`, that happens to have some the special methods. But that doensn't really make it a descriptor yet.

If you [read the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#invoking-descriptors) about how descriptors are invoked, youll see the mechanism that is used to invoke the descriptors methods. In your case this would mean `t.name` woud be roughly equivalent to:

```
type(t).__dict__['name'].__get__(t, type(t))
```

and `t1.name`:

```
type(t1).__dict__['name'].__get__(t1, type(t1))
```

`name` is looked up in the `__dict__` of the class, not of the instance, so that's where the difference is, `Test1.__dict__` doesn't have a descriptor called `name`:

```
>>> Test.__dict__['name']
<__main__.Descriptor object at 0x7f637a57bc90>
>>> Test1.__dict__['name']
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'name'
```

What you also should consider, is that your descriptor sets the `value` attribute on itself, that means all instances of `Test` will share the same value:

```
>>> t1 = Test(1)
init test
setting
>>> t2 = Test(2)
init test
setting
>>> t1.name
getting
2
>>> t2.name
getting
2
>>> t1.name = 0
setting
>>> t2.name
getting
0
```

I think that what yo acutally want to do is to set `value` on `instance` instead of `self`, that would get you the expected behaviour in `Test`.

Comment: I know this that It will add to the descriptor class, and it will be common for all instances of Test class, but my confusion is the line in documentation which tells that python will search through the instance dict, than class dict and dict of the bases of class, which has a descriptor class object. But in case of descriptor it is looking only for class dict, not for instance dict. what if I want to look for instance dict[link] (http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#definition-and-introduction)

Comment: the documentation is a little complicated here. the first paragraph is just the description of the normal lookup chain, descriptors are always looked up in the class dict, in an instance dict they're just normal objects which won't have their special methods called (hence he may in "Python **may** override the default behavior and invoke the descriptor method instead"). granted, the documentation could be a little more explicit here.

Comment: so you mean to say that class Test and Test1 are different where Test is the only class which will be acting as descriptor, not Test1.  And in documentation it is saying that ""in next comment""

Comment: ""The default behavior for attribute access is to get, set, or delete the attribute from an object’s dictionary. For instance, a.x has a lookup chain starting with a.__dict__['x'], then type(a).__dict__['x'], and continuing through the base classes of type(a) excluding metaclasses. If the looked-up value is an object defining one of the descriptor methods, then Python may override the default behavior and invoke the descriptor method instead.""

Comment: I think you were saying about last line that it may override. but I think it is saying that if in looked up value, if it finds object of descriptor than it will override the default behaviour and use overridden (overriden by us in descriptor class) and use overridden form of methods.

Comment: Why descriptors only look in only class dict and call their special method. If we are defining them as instance member then also it should work. Everywhere they will be object of Descriptor class only, no matter where we have defined them???

Comment: descriptors are a property (describe the behaviour) of a class, so they only make sense on a class, not on an instance. Many things in python require this behaviour. Consider the example about [methods](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods). Here `D` is an instance of `type`. If descriptors were called on instance attributes, `D.f` would always return a bound method, but you only want a bound method if you look up `d.f`. Likewise properties would brake...

Comment: thanks @mata. got it.. mean there is no meaning in assining descriptor object as a class instance attribute. It should always be class attribute.